# Git add an entire folder failure

Tags: git, amazon-web-services

I am new to git commands and I am encountering a problem.I am trying to **git add** an entire folder that contains folders to an aws codecommit repo, but when I type **git status** the only file the terminal shows in the staging environment is a **.DS_Store** file. I have tried **git add -A** but nothing seems to work. Anyone else encountered this?

Comment: Hey, could you post the output of `git status` and of `ls -la` in the directory you are trying to add?

Answer (score 0):

To add your folder on git, you'll use these 3 commands

## 1. git add <files>

prepare the files to be added to the next commit, at this stage, `git status` will show you what files are modified since last commit, and which files will be added to the next commit.

Maybe you don't see your files because you already commit it.

## 2. git commit -m 'DescribeYourWork'

this'll create a commit, a state of your code to rollback later or share with your team. At this stage, everything still on your local computer.

## 3. git push

This synchronize your commits with the server (code commit). You should be able to see your folder on AWS